# Rails and kaminari -- undefined method "total_pages"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang, kaminari, pagination

I add the this line in my .slim file:

```
= paginate cookies.permanent[:gyms].split('#').reverse, window: 1
```

Then, I get this error. So some configurations there I need write?

I know it is about kaminari gem. And There has no model about cookies.

And the log info is:

```
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 137ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x007f7d750d02d8>):
    25:                   = link_to gym.split('+')[1] do
    26:                     = gym.split('+')[3]
    27:         - temp_arr = cookies.permanent[:gyms].split('#').reverse
    28:         = paginate temp_arr, window: 1
    29:   //= render partial: "layouts/sidebar"
  app/views/statics/history.html.slim:28:in `_app_views_statics_history_html_slim__1135090183647085502_70088407005100'
  app/controllers/statics_controller.rb:168:in `history'
```

Comment: Include stack trace of the error and relevant code from controller in the question.

Comment: [docs](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#the-page-parameter-is-in-paramspage) You should have something like this: `@cookies = Cookie.page params[:page]` in the controller

Comment: @JagdeepSingh There has no controller, just cookies.

Comment: Can you show server logs for this request?

Comment: @eugene Cookie is an object? But I have no model about cookies.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Sure.

Comment: Seem you're pagination an array, then [paginate_array](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object) should work

Comment: I guess:
 `- array = Kaminari.paginate_array(cookies.permanent[:gyms].split('#').reverse)`  then 
`=  paginate array`
 should work

Comment: @eugene Can't work! See my log!

Comment: Sorry it should have something like this `.page(params[:page]).per(10)`

`- array = Kaminari.paginate_array(cookies.permanent[:gyms].split('#').reverse).page(params[:page]).per(10)`

Comment: @eugene Yeah, this access can let it work, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an `Array` so you should use `Kaminari.paginate_array` method:

https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object